# Последний подсчитанный номер дома

Tags: алгоритм, соревнование

Николай — опытный мотоциклист, и может вести мотоцикл, не концентрируясь полностью на вождении. В свою последнюю поездку он из спортивного интереса стал считать двойки в номерах домов вдоль проспекта, по которому он ехал. Сосчитать все дома не удалось, потому что в пути Николай-таки попал в аварию. Когда он пришел в себя в госпитале, на память ему пришло количество сосчитанных двоек. Теперь ему хочется определить номер дома, на котором он подсчитал последнюю двойку.

Итак на вход подается целое число, содержащее количество двоек, которые подсчитал Николай, а на выходе — номер дома, соответствующий количеству двоек, если исходные данные корректны.

Пример:

```
3 -> 20
4 -> ошибка
```

Определите номер дома, на котором Николай подсчитал свою последнюю двойку.

Comment: 4 -> 21
5 -> ошибка


Comment: Мне одному не понятно, что в задаче не сказано с какого дома он все-таки начал искать, да и других граничных условий нет... Пойду застрелюсь мылом!)

Comment: @DmoriaN, ошибаетесь. Это не учебное задание, а конкурс на лучший вопрос и ответ.

Comment: @avp, привет из будущего. Раз это конкурс, тогда закрываем как «слишком общий».

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, надо бы уточнить критерии определения учебных заданий. А то тревога в очереди лежит, но раз вопрос не был удалён, значит так и надо.

Comment: @Arhad, с такими подходами как у вас с сообщниками тут скоро никого, с кем хотелось бы поделиться не останется.

Comment: @Arhad Подскажите, пожалуйста причем тут учебное задание? Это вопрос–соревнование, который был задан в рамках конкурса.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, про отличие учебных заданий от соревнований понял. Просто предпосылки похожи («укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности» в причине закрытия).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Неэффективно, но коротко и быстро

```
#include <stdio.h>

main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  int n = av[1]? atoi(av[1]): 0, k = 0, i = 0;
  char s[20], *p;

  do {
    i++;
    sprintf (s,"%d",i);
    for (p = s; *p; p++)
      if (*p == '2')
         k++;
  } while (k < n);

  printf ("%d %s\n",i,k==n? "": "(Nick memory error)");
  return 0;
}
```

**UPDATE**

Потратим еще несколько минут на уменьшение и ускорение программки. Выбросим строку

```
char s[20], *p;
```

и заменим строки с `sprintf` и циклом `for` на

```
    int t;
    for (t = i; t; t /= 10)
      if (t % 10 == 2)
         k++;
```

IMHO так красивей.

Comment: Пардон, исправил насчет ошибки 

(это когда Николай не все цифры в номере дома успел прочесть).

Comment: IMHO, код должен быть правильный и быстрый, а уж потом красивый.

Comment: @FAndES, естественно, глюкавый и медленный код ужасен (антоним красивый).

Answer (score 3):

```
var i,j,n,count: Integer;
begin
  readln(n);
  count:=0;
  i:=1;
  while count<n do
  begin
    Inc(i);
    for j:=1 to Length(inttostr(i)) do
      if IntToStr(i)[j]='2' then Inc(count);
  end;
  if (count=n) and( n>0) then Writeln(i) else writeln('error');
  Readln;
end.
```

Answer (score 3):

Общая идея: бинпоиском сжимаем возможные значения для ответа, на каждом шаге оптимально считаем сколько двоек в числах до среднего числа (это делается за количество цифр в этом числе).

Сложность: `O(c*log(10^c))` где `c` - количество цифр в числе-ответе, то есть для k порядка 10^15 выполняется порядка 750 действий.

```
long long a[20]; // количество двоек во всех i-значных числах, включая числа с лидирующими нулями (например `a[2]=20`)

long long f(long long n){ //количество двоек во всех числах до n
    long long i=1,c=0;
    for (;i<=n;i*=10,c++); //ищем максимальную степень 10, так что 10^c>n
    i/=10;
    c--;
    long long res=a[c];
    int isfirst=1;
    while (i>0){  // постепенно понижаем степень добавляя ответ
        if ((n/i)%10==2){
            res+=n%i+1;
        }
        else{
            if ((n/i)%10>2){
                res+=i;
            }
        }
        res+=max(0ll,((n/i)%10-isfirst))*a[c];
        isfirst=0;
        c--;
        i/=10;
    }
    return res;
}

int main(){

    a[0]=0;
    a[1]=1;
    for (long long i=2,j=10;i<20;i++,j*=10){
        a[i]=a[i-1]*10+j; //посчитаем a[]
    }

    long long k;
    cin>>k;
    long long l=1,r=20*k; // левая и правая граница для бинпоиска
    while (l+1<r){
        long long m=(l+r)/2;
        if (f(m)>=k){
            r=m;
        }
        else{
            l=m;
        }
    }
    while (k<=f(r)){
        r--;
    }
    r++;
    if (f(r)!=k){
        cout<<"error\n";
    }
    else{
        cout<<r;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Предлагаю алгоритм, который не ходит по всем числам в поисках двоек, а применяет математические операции к входному числу для вычисления искомого числа.
За счет этого удается достичь сложности алгоритма O(n) и сильно сэкономить время.
П.С. Алгоритм отражает идею, он не претендует на работоспособность и требует отладки. Мне просто хочется показать вам ход мыслей.

```
int get_house(int n) {

int house = 0;  //искомый номер дома
//1.Вычисляем номер дома, если бы наш персонаж считал двойки только в разряде единиц

house = (n-1) * 10 + 2;  //например, при n=4 получаем house=32

//2.В цикле добавляем учет более высоких разрядов. При этом учитываем только целое количество двоек.

int cur_position = 1;   //текущий просматриваемый разряд

int extra_n = 0;    //количество оставшихсяколичеств двоек, которые нужно насчитать на шаге 3 (объяснение - в теле цикла)

int twoes_on_prev_positions = 1;    //сколько "2" в предыдущих относительно cur_position разрядах

while(true) {

    if(n < twoes_on_prev_positions)

        return -1;  //error

    // На каждом cur_position разряде "2" встречается каждые (10^(cur_position+1)) 
раз на протяжении (10^cur_position) значений

    // например, для разряда десятков (т.е. при cur_position==1) "2" встречается каждые 100 раз на протяжении 10 значений: от 20 до 29

    int cur_times = (10^(cur_position+1));  //частота повторения

    int cur_length = (10^cur_position); //протяженность встречаемости

    int full_nums = (n-twoes_on_prev_positions)/cur_length; //считаем количество полных протяженностей, в которые укладывается n

    extra_n = (n-twoes_on_prev_positions)%cur_length;//запоминаем количество неполных протяженностей, т.е. остаток

    //например, при n==27 на cur_position==1 количество домов встречается в полном наборе дважды: 20-29 и 120-129, т.е. full_nums = 2

    //в остатке еще 7 двоек, которые не укладываются в полный набор и будут сохранены в переменную extra_n для шага 3.

    if(full_nums <= 0) {    //если в текущем разряде "2" не встречается такое количество раз, чтобы покрыть всю протяженность, то

        //значит - пора выйти из цикла

        break;

    }

    house = full_nums * cur_times;  //насчитываем указанное количество полных протяженностей

    twoes_on_prev_positions = cur_length + twoes_on_prev_positions*(10^(cur_position-1));   //добавляем количество двоек за текущий разряд

    cur_position++;

}

//3.Досчитываем нецелое количество двоек

house -= (house/10^(cur_position)) * 10^(cur_position); //обнуляем cur_position разряд

house += extra_n * (10^(cur_position)); //добавляем extra_n не в cur_position разряд

//4. Возвращаем ответ

return house;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Функция Get2Count возвращает искомое число для N, -1 в случае ошибки. Работает довольно быстро, так как нет преобразований в строку.

```
function Get2Count(N: Integer): Integer;
  function Get2(N: Integer): Integer;
  begin
    Result:= 0;
    if N = 0 then
      Exit;
    if N mod 10 = 2 then
      Result:= 1;
    Result:= Result + Get2(N div 10);
  end;    
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result:= -1;
  if N < 1 then
    Exit;
  I:= 0;
  Result:= 0;
  repeat
    Inc(Result);
    I:= I + Get2(Result);
  until I >= N;
  if I > N then
    Result:= -1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Ходим по числам в поиске двоек. Нашли - +1 к числу `cal_n`, и переходим к следующему разряду числа. Делаем это, пока подсчитанное количество двоек будет равно числу, которое запомнили. Если введено некорректное число, то комп выдаст ошибку, но и подскажет, где произошла авария.

```
int main (void)
{ 
int en_n, cal_n = 0, num1 = 1, num2, two = 2, ten = 10;
cout << "Enter number : ";
cin >> en_n;
while (en_n != cal_n)
{
  num1++; num2=num1;
  two = 2; ten = 10;
  while ((num2 - two) >= 0)
  {
     if (en_n != cal_n) 
     {   
        if (((num2 - two)%ten)==0)
        {
          cal_n++;
          num2-=two;
          two*=10; ten*=10;
        }
        else 
        {
          while ((num2%ten)!=0)
          {num2--;}
          two*=10; ten*=10;
        }
     }
     else
     {
      num2 = -100;
      cout << "Error  . . . I think, he has crashed near ";
     }
  }
}
cout <<"house number - "<< num1 <<" ." << endl;
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Конкурс уже закончился, но вот алгоритм, основаный на том, что между 0 и 10^n содержится n * 10^(n-1) двоек ( или любой другой цифры кроме нуля )

Я позволил себе усложнить задание и добавить возможность поиска любой цифры от 1 до 9, но по умолчанию используется 2. Кроме того в задании не указано в какую сторону велся счет и откуда начинался. Поэтому есть возможность скомпилировать программу с выводом результата в виде промежутка значений на котором находится указаное количество вхождений. В таком случае ответ найдется всегда.

в архиве:

```
finger.exe - результат в виде промежутка
finger_zs.exe - результат при счете от нуля
    запускать из консоли

make.cmd - компиляция finger.exe
make_zero_start.cmd - компиляция finger_zs.exe

finger_of_dread.c - исходник ( 305 строк считая множество коментариев )
readme.rtf - описание правил, использованых в реализации

pow_int_error - демонстрация неточности приведения к степени pow
```

[скачать с rghost](http://rghost.net/39850021)